# Как в pyTelegramBotAPI запросить ввод и получить значение при вводе?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я использую **TelegramBot python**
Мне нужно, чтобы после отправки от бота сообщения, он ждал **новое значение**, чтобы продолжить работу.

**Пример:**
Пользователь вводит "1" бот принимает и отвечает на сообщение "Введите следующее значение"  и это главный момент, бот ждет получения значения, он не должен запускать функцию с этим значением, а просто получить!!!

Ввод от пользователя - Получение ботом - Отправка от бота сообщения - Ждет сообщения - Ввод от пользователя - **Получение ботом** - Сохраняет значение

То есть
bot.register_next_step_handler(send, inputBot()) мне не подходит

```
import telebot


def inputBot():
    res = ???? Функция которая ждет значение и возвращает
    return res


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text(message):
    msg = message.text
    
    if msg == '1':
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите следующее значение".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html')

        a = inputBot()         #Вот на этом этапе мне нужно получить значение которое человек ввел, 

        # Именно ПОЛУЧИТЬ а не запустить функцию с полученным новым значение
        # bot.register_next_step_handler(send, inputBot()).  Это меня не устраивает, мне нужно получить значение


    elif msg == '2':
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def inputBot(message, text):
    def ret(message):
        a.clear()
        a.append(message.text)
        return False

    a.clear()
    mes = send(message, text)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, ret)
    while a == []:
        pass
    return a[0]

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text(message):
    msg = message.text
    
    if msg == '1':
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите следующее значение".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html')

        a = inputBot(message, 'Введите следующее значение')
        print(a) # Вводит значение, которое мы запросили у пользователя
```